# Is there a way to mask text in an editbox in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text, passwords, masking, editbox

is there any way to mask text that is inputted into an edit box?

I have to produce a really basic prototype GUI that will take the username and password from the user and they both work, but I want to replace the user's password with asterisks instead of plain text.

Instead of having 'bob' display in the edit box I would like it to display '* * *' for example.

Security does not matter at this point as it's simply a visual representation with no proper use as of now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use somebody else's. In this case, the function [passcode](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6590-passcode) from the Matlab File Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use my submission [Fex: passfield](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47210-passfield).

[image: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/screenshots/22617/original.jpg]